# SAS conditional hypothesis in Ttest

Tags: sas

var of: mean salary. 
If I want to run a Ttest on the data and my HO is that 70% of the employess has a salary over 5000, how do I include the 70% into my hypothesis?

```
PROC TTEST DATA=comb5 H0=5000 SIDES=U ALPHA=0.05;
VAR mean_all;
RUN;
```

Comment: I don't think that's a t-test but I could be wrong...

Comment: t-tests only allow you to test if the means of different groups are different. You're interested in testing the 70th percentile, which is not the same thing. Try asking on Cross-Validated.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need is a one sample binomial test, which can be done within `proc freq`. You will first need to create a flag that shows if the salary is > 5000, then you can run the binomial test against that variable.

Check the [online documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/63104/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_freq_sect010.htm) for options on the different methods available and how to change the confidence interval (the default is 95%).

```
/* create dummy dataset */
data have;
call streaminit(123); /* set the randon number seed */
do i = 1 to 1000; /* create 1000 rows */
salary = rand('bernoulli',0.7)+5000; /* create salary (either 5000 or 5001) */
test_flag = (salary>5000); /* create binomial flag to show if salary is > 5000 */
output;
end;
run;

/* run hypothesis that proportion of salaries > 5000 is 0.7 */
proc freq data=have;
table test_flag / binomial (p=0.7 level='1') /* other options available here if required */;
run;
```